Unable to load Swagger UI on http://localhost:{port}/swagger endpoint for net framework
Packages Used:
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net48" />

SwaggerConfig.cs
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\webApi.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Api Documentation");
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
    }
}

Unable to load the swagger Ui and even it's not providing any build error, So unable to find the issue.
Here you can check the error message :
enter image description here

post your error please
